# How to integrate Silk Central with an external system?

Tags: automated-tests, silk-central

I would like to run the tests from Silk Central on a distributed environment. i.e. on different machines. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

As I did not get any answer from here, I tried myself using the trial version of Silk Central I installed. There is a provision to add multiple execution servers in Silk Central test manager. Using this option we can make this possible.

Requirements:-
1. We need to install Silk Central Execution server on each of this remote machines
2. There should be connectivity between the machine on which the test manager is installed and the machines on which the Execution servers are installed

After doing all these, we can configure the required machine as the execution server for an execution through the deployment tab